# show that a function is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

If $A\approx B$ then $A^{C}\approx B^{C}$ where $B^{C}:=\{f|f:C\to B\}$

by ''$\approx$'' I mean equinumerous

Proof:
By hypothesis $A\approx B\Rightarrow \exists T:A\to B$ which is bijective and $\exists T^{-1}B\to A$ which is also bijective.

let now 
$\sigma: B^{C}\to A^{C}$ be defined as
$\sigma: f\to T^{-1}\circ f$, for some $f\in B^{C}$

how to show that this function is bijective?

1-1

$\sigma(f_{1})=\sigma(f_{2})\Rightarrow T^{-1}\circ f_{1}=T^{-1}\circ f_{2}\Rightarrow f_{1}=f_{2}$ right?

surjective??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of injectivity is right, because you have
$$T^{-1}\circ f_1=T^{-1}\circ f_2$$
Now, pre-compose both sides by $T$, to obtain
 $$T\circ T^{-1}\circ f_1=T\circ T^{-1}\circ f_2$$
But $T\circ T^{-1}$ is the identity function on $A$, hence you can conclude.

For surjectivity, let $f:C\longrightarrow A$ be an element of $A^C$. You need a pre-image of $f$ via $\sigma$, i.e. a function $g:C\longrightarrow B$ such that $\sigma(g)=f$. Take $g:=T\circ f$. To verify that this is the right one you only need to apply the definition of $\sigma$, so:
$$\sigma(g)=\sigma(T\circ f)=T^{-1}\circ T\circ f=f$$
as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof of injectivity is fine.

For surjectivity, take $f:C\to A$. Then let $f' = T \circ f$. What is $\sigma(f')$?